# Paypal Cart Discount

Tags: paypal

How do I add code to give a discount of $19.99 if my paypal cart total is over $ 99.00?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="hnsabc@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Apex Creatine .47lbs">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="91037 97366 Promo">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="35.99">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
```

Comment: I am also looking for something like this.